# Creation of a asp.net 5 project to hold common js modules

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, javascript, typescript1.6

I have multiple asp.net 5 mvc 6 projects for specific types of applications.  Each of these applications will be using ReactJS and typescript 1.6 (TSX files).  I want to have a project that will hold common js modules that the specific applications can each reference.  Is this possible? and if so, how would i proceed.

Comment: I recommend using bower or npmjs for managing js files.

Comment: Are you saying to package the common JS files from the common project and then reference that package in the specific projects?  I wasn't aware that bower or npmjs could do this.

Comment: You would not reference them as NuGet packages but use the javascript package manager of your choice to install them

Answer (score 1):

I've been told that in beta8 we will be able to packages views in the nuget package created by building a class library package project. I assume it will be a way to package any kind of static files so you should be able to do it also with js files

Comment: Yes, we'll be adding support for packing random files in the nupkg. However, for js files I recommend bower, npmjs or another js package manager